# How can I find out names of applications to remove them in terminal?

Tags: command-line, package-management, startup-applications

I have tried to uninstall many apps in terminal because some apps are not shown in Ubuntu Software app. Every time I do this I have to search the Internet because it's hard to know how to write the name of an app in the terminal. For example, FreeOffice's name in terminal is `sofmaker-freeoffice-2023`, and it is different for other apps.

Is there any way to know what name to use the uninstall applications using the terminal without searching the Internet?

Comment: It's softmaker, not sofmaker, which proves your point (hard to know how to write). ;)

Comment: Please try using Synaptic.

Comment: dpkg --list | grep "name"

Answer (score 7):

This answers the specific question "Is there any way to know what name to use the uninstall applications using the terminal without searching the Internet?" and "How can I find out names of applications to remove them in terminal?". If you want to use that information to also remove it using the terminal, knowing the name of the executable that launches the program may not be enough.

For applications that are in your menu system, searching your system's `.desktop` launchers is a good way. `.desktop` launchers are little text files with the `.desktop` extension, which are used to tell the operating system various things about an installed application.

You can find such launchers based on what is displayed in the menu. For example, the launcher for LO Writer will contain the string on a line starting with `Name=`. When you open that launcher in a text editor, you will see the executable specified after `Exec=`.

You can use any tool you want to search a file based on content, however, I have a little script, which I've named `whichdesktop`, that searches `.desktop` files:

Content of `whichdesktop`:

```bash
#!/bin/bash
IFS=$" :"
DIR="$HOME/.local/share/applications"
for d in $XDG_DATA_DIRS; do
    d=$(echo "$d" | sed -e 's/\/$//')
    [ -d $d/applications ] && DIR="$DIR $d/applications"
done
find -L $DIR -name '*.desktop' -exec grep -H "$1" {} \;
```

It makes a list of the directories where `.desktop` launchers may be installed, and then invokes `find` to search only these directories.

For example, if I'm interested in finding what the executable for LibreOffice Writer is called, I run:

```
$ whichdesktop "LibreOffice Writer"
/usr/share/applications/libreoffice-writer.desktop:Name=LibreOffice Writer
$ cat /usr/share/applications/libreoffice-writer.desktop | grep Exec=
Exec=libreoffice --writer %U
Exec=libreoffice --writer
```

which shows that the executable is called `libreoffice`.

Answer (score 0):

A partial help might be the auto completion, which is pretty useful for apt:

```
sudo apt remove sof->->
```

where the two `->` arrows shall indicate the tab key, will show you all candidates for removing, taking only installed software into account.

But you still have to know how the name starts. At least it will detect misspellings.

The apropos command might be useful, to find programs, where you know a part of the name or can guess essential parts of the description:

```
apropos office
```

should give you a list of programs where the name contains the string "office" or the description somehow matches. From there, you can often narrow down the options.